# Error uploading the application in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, xcode-organizer

I have this error. What I can do?

**Error ITMS-9000: "Invalid image path - No image found at the path referenced under key CFBundleIcons AppIcon120x120**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I found it !!!!!!!!**

**Its a bug from Xcode 6. Only remove the icon CarPlay from App Icon Source and works perfectly !!! =D**